# Negotiate Header was invalid error with Spring Security Kerberos extension/IE, Firefox/AD

Tags: jboss7.x, spring-security-kerberos

We are configuring Spring Security Kerberos extension in OWF 7 (Ozone Widget Framework) on JBoss AS 7.1.1. We see the following error:

```
23:01:44,172 WARN  [org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter] (http--10.200.69.103-8080-2) Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesfull
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:69) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:86) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:120) [spring-security-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:48) [spring-security-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) [org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:67) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2.jar:]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(GSSHeader.java:80) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:287) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:267) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:146) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:136) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2.jar:]
    ... 26 more
```

I saw a post on stack overflow (["Defective token detected" error (NTLM not Kerberos) with Kerberos/Spring Security/IE/Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973355/defective-token-deteced-error-ntlm-not-kerberos-with-kerberos-spring-securit)) and thought someone can help me with our situation.

Our setup:

JDK 1.6.0_31
JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago) Kernel 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64
Windows Server 2008 Active Directory
Spring Security Kerberos Extension M2 (configured following the instructions provided in their blog: http://blog.springsource.com/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos/ )
Firefox 21 (runs on a VM)
IE 10 (runs on a VM)

From the previous post listed above it appears like AD server is sending an NTLM token to IE and IE is sending this to application. We have our Application Server (JBoss), AD Server and client (IE, Firefox) on different machines
joined to the same domain. Below is the krb5.conf file from /etc folder of the linux box where JBoss is:

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
 default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
 permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
 dns_lookup_realm = true
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 passwd_check_s_address = false
 noaddresses = true
udp_preference_limit = 1
 ccache_type = 3
 kdc_timesync = 0
 kdc_timesync = 0
[domain_realm]
 .enterpriselabs.com = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 enterpriselabs.com = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 .cdc.lab = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 cdc.lab = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 .dcas-i-2-069103 = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 .enterpriselabs.mycompany.com = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 dcas-i-2-069103 = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 enterpriselabs.mycompany.com = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 mcc-ad01.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 mcc-ad03.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 scr0-i-1-069137.scr0.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com = SCR0.ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
 ssbox8.cdc.lab = ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM
[realms]
ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM = {
 kdc = mcc-ad01.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:88
 master_kdc = mcc-ad01.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:88
 kpasswd = mcc-ad01.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:464
 kpasswd_server = mcc-ad01.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:464
 kdc = mcc-ad03.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:88
 master_kdc = mcc-ad03.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:88
 kpasswd = mcc-ad03.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:464
 kpasswd_server = mcc-ad03.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:464
}
SCR0.ENTERPRISELABS.mycompany.COM = {
 kdc = scr0-i-1-069137.scr0.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:88
 master_kdc = scr0-i-1-069137.scr0.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:88
 kpasswd = scr0-i-1-069137.scr0.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:464
 kpasswd_server = scr0-i-1-069137.scr0.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com:464
}
```

Under [domain_realm] block the first 2 entries won't have .mycompany in them. Is this a problem?

We generated the keytab file by running the following command:
ktpass /princ HTTP/jaguar.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com@ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM /mapuser jaguar@ENTERPRISELABS.MYCOMPANY.COM -crypto all -pass password -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out c:\jaguar-host.keytab

We copied the keytab file generated to the WEB-INF/classes folder of our application on JBoss. When we contacted our tech support they also mentioned that test user accounts created have 'Kerberos Authentication' 
checkbox checked. I think when we login to the domain we are authenticated using kerberos not NTLM (I don't know whether it is correct or not). But, this didn't help us getting rid of the above problem. 
I used fiddler and saw 'NTLM Authentication' in one of the screens. Please help us in debugging this problem. I think the problem is in AD somewhere and don't know where to look for answers. Do we have to follow any specific 
steps to make sure our AD is configured right? Is there a way to configure AD server to send Kerberos token?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that jaguar.enterpriselabs.mycompany.com is DNS A record hostname instead of CNAME alias?

I think I had a similar error message when I created the keytab using a DNS alias hostname (CNAME).

When browser asks KDC for the ticket, it always uses the DNS A record hostname, regardless of the hostname you have in browser address bar. Users can still use CNAME alias hostnames to access the site, but the keytab must be created using A record hostname.

Comment: That is the name of the host. We could resolve the issue. The issue was caused because there were multiple SPNs created. We removed all the SPNs, created the test user, set that user as SPN and generated the keytab file afresh.

Comment: @StrangeLoop - Please write your comment above as an answer instead, and self-mark it as accepted.