# Kerberos authentication not working with spring security

Tags: kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

We are working on Kerberos login authentication, It was working fine but now we are getting the below exception while hitting the URL and its not redirecting to the home page.

Suggest some solution would be much appreciated.

```
10:44:20,145 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (http-/127.0.0.1:6900-3) Cannot forward to error page for request  as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

10:44:20,150 WARN  [org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter] (http-/127.0.0.1:6900-2) Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate YH4GBisGAQUFAqB0MHKgMDAuBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHqI+BDxOVExNU1NQAAEAAACXsgjiCAAIADQAAAAMAAwAKAAAAAYBsR0AAAAPUEMzMDYxMzU2NTI1RU1JUkFURVM=: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesfull

    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:69) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:85) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167) [spring-security-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:155) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88) [spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]

Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:67) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 50 more

Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)

    at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(GSSHeader.java:97) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:306) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:871) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:544) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:151) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:142) [spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 53 more

10:44:20,395 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (http-/127.0.0.1:6900-2) Cannot forward to error page for request [/app/rest/account] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

10:44:20,262 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (http-/127.0.0.1:6900-4) Cannot forward to error page for request [/protected/authentication_check.gif] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Comment: Last time I saw something similar it was caused by providing SPNEGO token where raw Kerberos token was expected. Not telling it is your case though, there is not enough information to tell ...

Comment: can you check my log - added complete trace

Comment: Unlikely to be the wrong token type though if it used towork. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973355/defective-token-deteced-error-ntlm-not-kerberos-with-kerberos-spring-securit

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you should check the correctness of the SPN names. 
It seems that the browser had sent to the application an NTLM token instead of a Kerberos token. This can happen  if the browser receive an error response from Kerberos when asking for a service ticket. 
In my case, the monitoring of the network traffic between the client and the kerberos server had shown that the browser had received the error ERR-S-PRINCIPAL-UNKNOWN (7) from kerberos because a SPN was not correctly mapped into active directory.