# "GSSException Defective token detected" - when trying to Authenticate to Tomcat running on Windows using Kerberos

Tags: java, windows, active-directory, kerberos, gssapi

I am struggling to authenticate to a Java web container (I've tried both Tomcat and Jetty) when running on Windows 2012.

Every time I try the Negotiate auth scheme I get an error: `org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)`

***Steps to reproduce***

Start out by setting up a Windows Server 2012 or 2016 instance and install active directory domain services.

In my example, I created:

- **NETBIOS Domain:** NICKIS
- **Dns domain:** nickis.life

Create the kerberos subject user on Active Directory

IMPORTANT: MAKE SURE THAT THE FIRST NAME, LAST NAME AND FULL NAME ARE THE SAME!

The new user in my case is:

**DN** = `CN=kerberos500,CN=Users,DC=nickis,DC=life`

**login+domain** = `kerberos500@nickis.life`

**NETBIOS\samAccountName** = `NICKIS\kerberos500`

Run the setspn command from the Windows Active Directory Server

```
setspn -A HTTP/nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE kerberos500
```

Example output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>setspn -A HTTP/nickis.life kerberos500
Checking domain DC=nickis,DC=life 
Registering ServicePrincipalNames for CN=kerberos500,CN=Users,DC=nickis,DC=life
        HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life
Updated object
```

Run the ktpass command from the Windows Active Directory Server

```
ktpass -out c:\Users\Administrator\kerberos500.keytab -princ HTTP/nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE -mapUser kerberos500 -mapOp set -pass XXXXpasswordforkerberos500userXXXX -crypto DES-CBC-MD5 -pType KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL +DesOnly
```

Example output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ktpass -out c:\Users\Administrator\kerberos500.keytab -princ HTTP/nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE -mapUser kerberos500 -mapOp set -pass xxxxxxxx -crypto DES-CBC-MD5 -pType KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL +DesOnly
Targeting domain controller: WIN-OVV6VHBGIB8.nickis.life
Using legacy password setting method
Successfully mapped HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life to kerberos500.
Key created.
Output keytab to c:\Users\Administrator\kerberos500.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 71 HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 3 etype 0x3 (DES-CBC-MD5) keylength 8 (0xcd07200bea625d20)
Account kerberos500 has been set for DES-only encryption.
```

At this point, you will now have a keytab file:

```
c:\Users\Administrator\kerberos500.keytab
```

And a user principal:

```
HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE
```

These are the 2 inputs that are needed to provide to the GSSApi to get single sign on with Kerberos.

So I deployed those inputs to my web container's kerberos security realm in the Hadoop security module.

**Curl test** I tried unsuccessfully to use curl to test it:

`curl --negotiate -u : http://nickis.life:8080/my/webapp`

**Internet Explorer test** I also tried using Internet Explorer. I added `nickis.life` domain to the Trusted Roles in Internet Explorer. Then I launch the site in internet explorer: http://nickis.life:8080

Either way, I get the error below:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.KerberosAuthenticationHandler.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticationHandler.java:398) ~[hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar:?]

...

Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.KerberosAuthenticationHandler$2.run(KerberosAuthenticationHandler.java:365) ~[hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.KerberosAuthenticationHandler$2.run(KerberosAuthenticationHandler.java:347) ~[hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.KerberosAuthenticationHandler.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticationHandler.java:347) ~[hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar:?]
```

I am stumped. NOTE: I have found several links around here and there but none of them were all inclusive on the steps that were followed like I have summed up here, and none of the solutions provided within worked for me.

- I am attempting kerberos login from a different machine on the domain than the server is running on
- I have tried all sorts of combinations of keytab generation variations none have worked.
- There is no duplicate SPN.
- I tried setting up the DNS in the domain server as an `A` record.
- I wonder maybe if there's some kerberos windows server setup steps and Microsoft employee verified that this should not be the case here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/db15ad96-e269-436e-952f-fe9dfb39da8a/setting-up-a-test-windows-server-active-directory-for-kerberos-testing?forum=winserverDS

Can anyone trace what I am screwing up here?

UPDATE:

- I have AD server with domain set to `fusionis.life`, and the AD server is `WIN-OVV6VHBGIB8.fusionis.life`
- I moved the tomcat server to another windows machine in the domain. `DESKTOP-VTPBE99.fusionis.life`
- I opened `dnsmgmt.msc` and added a "Forward Lookup Zone" with "kerberos500.nickis.life" with A HOST set to the IP of the `DESKTOP-VTPBE99.fusionis.life` box.
- I deleted the AD account, recreated it, then re-generated the keytab again as suggested in one of the answers on the ticket.

`C:\Users\Administrator>ktpass -out c:\Users\Administrator\kerberos500.keytab -princ HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE -mapUser kerberos500 -mapOp set -pass xxxxxxxxx -crypto ALL -pType KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
Targeting domain controller: WIN-OVV6VHBGIB8.fusionis.life
Using legacy password setting method
Successfully mapped HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life to kerberos500.
Key created.
Key created.
Key created.
Key created.
Key created.
Output keytab to c:\Users\Administrator\kerberos500.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 67 HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 4 etype 0x1 (DES-CBC-CRC) keylength 8 (0x04e30b9183ba8389)
keysize 67 HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 4 etype 0x3 (DES-CBC-MD5) keylength 8 (0x04e30b9183ba8389)
keysize 75 HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 4 etype 0x17 (RC4-HMAC) keylength 16 (0xe39a141de38abd8750bf9c0bf49fd1c5)
keysize 91 HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 4 etype 0x12 (AES256-SHA1) keylength 32 (0xe368a1b060cfe4816f522c1c5f62ca07fe201ed96c6d018054dfbd5b86251892)
keysize 75 HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 4 etype 0x11 (AES128-SHA1) keylength 16 (0x1b1a548fa2893a78c6f4c7f9c482b614)`

- I saved the keytab updated file on the server, then updated the Service Principal to `HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE`
- I logged into tomcat machine as a domain user, added http://kerberos500.nickis.life to the trusted sites, then navigated to http://kerberos500.nickis.life:8764
- I checked all combinations of the encryption check boxes in the kerberos500 AD "account" tab.

Now i'm getting a new error...

`GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails)`

UPDATE:

Resolved finally. I got this final error because I needed `fusionis.life` to be on the same host as `nickis.life`

Comment: This is a very broad question. For a better shot at getting it answered, I would suggest adding the kerberos and spnego tags to it. Maybe throw in a bounty as well. Just my .02.

Comment: @JohnRSmith ok will do.

Comment: Someone mentioned it could be case sensitivity is causing my woes

Comment: I doubt its case sensitivity.  A lot of this stuff is case insensitive, like a web browser URL, for example.  There could be some Active Directory implications here impacting the scenario.

Comment: Sorry I had a problem with Windows + VirtualBox which killed the VM's i had to test this. I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually working through the suggestion now. Unfortunately it takes a bunch of time to get everything set up differently for the suggested answer. no solution yet.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error “*Defective token detected*” likely means that an [ntlm](/questions/tagged/ntlm) token was detected.  That’s what the Negotiate mechanism uses inside popular web browsers if [kerberos](/questions/tagged/kerberos) fails - when not instructed by the web server otherwise.  On [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) operating systems, the IE web browser on it (and Firefox, if configured correctly) basically says, if you won’t do Kerberos, I’m going to send you an NTLM token.  And the server replies “no way” I don’t even know NTLM so I’m calling what you sent me defective.  Since you seem to be setting this up for the first time, you likely did not configure any fallback mechanism (such as NTLM) for when Kerberos fails, therefore, that error message.  We solve this by understanding why Kerberos is failing.  I think I see the reason for the failure in your question, in two places, related to SPNs and Trusted Sites.  Even if you resolve those two items, there is a third reason and fourth reason why it could continue to fail, related to encryption.

1. The [spn](/questions/tagged/spn) for the HTTP service does not match the URL entered by the browser.   These need to match, otherwise Kerberos will fail.  To work, the browser should be using: http://kerberos500.nickis.life:8080, not http://nickis.life:8080.  I say that based on what I saw in your [keytab](/questions/tagged/keytab) creation syntax.  In that you’ve coded the SPN as such:  HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE.  That’s why you need to use http://kerberos500.nickis.life:8080. The browser won’t know how to get to your web service when you tell it to go to http://nickis.life:8080.  With that top URL, the browser assumes it needs to find a web service running on your Active Directory[domaincontroller](/questions/tagged/domaincontroller) (anything with just nickis.life is assumed to run on the Domain Controller).  DCs should never run web servers for security reasons.
2. You’ll need to add http://kerberos500.nickis.life as a Trusted Site under IE settings.  Alternatively, *.nickis.life would work as well.   (You called it Trusted Roles, when it’s actually called Trusted Sites).
3. You are restricting the Kerberos encryption type to DES-CBC-MD5.  Starting with Windows Server 2008 Active Directory R2, DES is disabled by default.  DES is an outdated and generally insecure encryption type these days.  Much better to use AES128 or even better, AES256.  You can fix that by re-generating the keytab per my example below.
4. In the AD user account kerberos500, go to the Account tab, scroll to the bottom, and check all the boxes for DES, AES 128, and AES 256, and OK you’re way out of the dialog boxes.  You must check these boxes even if you did everything right above, or else Kerberos authentication will still fail.

How to properly re-generate the keytab: You should not run the setspn -a command to add an SPN to an AD user whenever you are planning to make a keytab associated with that user account.  The reason why is because the keytab creation command adds the SPN to the user account as part of the command.  If your scenario doesn’t work after following my advice above, then you’ll need to remove the SPN via setspn -D like below:

```
setspn -D HTTP/nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE kerberos500
```

And the re-generate the keytab afterwards, my only change is that I told it to use all encryption types.  The client and server will agree on the strongest common one during the authentication process.

```
ktpass -out c:\Users\Administrator\kerberos500.keytab -princ HTTP/nickis.life@NICKIS.LIFE -mapUser kerberos500 -mapOp set -pass XXXXpasswordforkerberos500userXXXX -crypto ALL -pType KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
```

Then replace the old keytab with the new one.  For additional in-depth information on keytabs, you can read more from my technical article on how to create Kerberos keytabs here:  [Kerberos Keytabs – Explained](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36470.kerberos-keytabs-explained.aspx).  I frequently go back and edit it based on questions I see here in this forum.

By the way, *HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life* is a service principal, not a user principal as you wrote in your question.   I only use web browsers to test Kerberos in HTTP scenarios like this one, I don’t use cURL.

I am positive if you diligently go through all four points I’ve highlighted above, you will resolve this problem.

**EDIT1:** This answer assumes you have an HTTP service running  on a host with the fully-qualified domain name of kerberos500.nickis.life.  If you don't have such a host with that name, my answer will slightly change.  Please let me know if any.

**EDIT2:** To achieve the objective of authentication using the URL of http://nickis.life:8080, then you may keep on using the same keytab you already created.

On the AD account NICKIS\kerberos500, go to the Account tab, scroll to the bottom, and check the box for "Use Kerberos DES encryption types for this account".

Then enable DES encryption itself at the AD domain level via Group Policy.  To do that, conduct the following:

1. Open up Group Policy Management Console (GPMC).
2. Edit Default Domain Policy GPO.  (Its safer to create a new domain-level GPO instead and edit that, but that's up to you).
3. Navigate to Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > “Network Security: Configure Encryption types allowed for Kerberos” and check the both checkboxes for DES_CBC_MD5 and DES_CBC_MD5.  IMPORTANT:  In that same Group Policy, also ensure the checkboxes for RC4,  AES128, and AES256 are also checked.  Those encryption types won't be used for tickets to your web site, but they will for everything else in the domain. and OK you're way out of the dialog boxes and close the GPMC.
4. Run the 'gpupdate /force' command on both the DC server and the client.
5. Run 'klist purge' on the client to purge all Kerberos tickets.
6. In the web browser, clear the cache and delete all cookies.
7. Ensure that the DC server allows port 8080 TCP inbound.
8. Try it again.

Reference: [Windows Configurations for Kerberos Supported Encryption Type](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2011/05/30/windows-configurations-for-kerberos-supported-encryption-type/)

EDIT 3: Avoid running Kerberos KDC (the DC), client and server on the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973355/defective-token-detected-error-ntlm-not-kerberos-with-kerberos-spring-securi/3410254#3410254) machine.  That is a classic recipe for getting the "Defective token error" even if you've done everything else right.

EDIT 4: (Final update which was verified by the OP):  Looked at the new ktpass keytab creation output, and I saw this: Targeting domain controller: WIN-OVV6VHBGIB8.fusionis.life. Now, the defined SPN in the keytab is HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life. The AD domain name is different from the SPN you defined, so this is not going to work unless you have some kind of trust setup between these domains. If you don't have a trust, you need to use an SPN of HTTP/kerberos500.fusionis.life instead.

Comment: This answer assumes you have an HTTP service running  on a host with the fully-qualified domain name of kerberos500.nickis.life.  If you don't have such a host with that name, my answer will slightly change.  Please let me know if any.

Comment: @T-Heron thanks for the great response. I would like to use http://nickis.life:8080 . What would I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: This means your HTTP service will be running on your Domain Controller/KDC.  I am just confirming that you are OK with that?

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza - I just added an EDIT2 to the Answer to allow it to work using the URL of http://nickis.life:8080.  You can keep on using the same keytab in that case.

Comment: IMPORTANT:  In that same Group Policy, please ensure the checkboxes for RC4,  AES128, and AES256 are also checked!  Those encryption types won't be used for tickets to your web site, but they will for everything else in the domain.

Comment: @T-Heron Re: "This means your HTTP service will be running on your Domain Controller/KDC. I am just confirming that you are OK with that?" well in my test situation it is but not in my production scenario it won't be.

Comment: Understood.  This is a complicated scenario you are testing, using an encryption protocol (DES) that has been disabled by default in Active Directory since version Windows Server 2008 R2.  The current standard is Windows Server 2016 which uses AES256.  I've done the best I could here with this answer, I don't think I can cover all of the possible nuances you might run forward into while testing all of this out.

Comment: I've given you the framework of how to solve this.  You just have to keep at it, you'll get it solved.  Once you get done testing on your DC, you'll have to revert to my original answer to get Kerberos SSO to AD working on a separate host.

Comment: I've added an "EDIT3" to wrap this up.  It basically says to avoid running Kerberos KDC (the DC), client and server on the same machine, which is a classic recipe for getting the "Defective token" error even if you've done everything else right.

Comment: So sorry for the huge delay. Now I'm stuck at `GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails)` I tried every combination of everything you suggested.

Comment: There are so many comments now this may get moved to chat in the system, if it does, stay with me.  I looked at your new ktpass keytab creation output, and I saw this:  *Targeting domain controller: WIN-OVV6VHBGIB8.fusionis.life*.  Now, your defined SPN in the keytab is *HTTP/kerberos500.nickis.life*.  The AD domain name is different from the SPN you defined, so this is not going to work unless you have some kind of trust setup between these domains.  If you don't have a trust, I think you need to use an SPN of  *HTTP/kerberos500.fusionis.life* instead.

Comment: hell yeah breakthrough! your last comment did it

Comment: Note to readers:  When I said "You’ll need to add http://kerberos500.nickis.life as a Trusted Site under IE settings" I actually meant "Local Intranet" sites.

Answer (score 1):

for me, the issue is that the SPN configured is different from the url specified.

So let's say the SPN is `HTTP/serviceX.domain.com`, when the service is accessed, it should be accessed through `http://serviceX.doamin.com`, otherwise, it would throw a `Defective token` error.

(I also found all Keberos related error messages pretty confusing, maybe MIT purposely made it difficult to understand, correspondingly would be even more difficult to hack.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**Solution 1**

run this on windows cmd:

ksetup /addkdc  
ksetup /addhosttorealmmap

and set SPNEGO settings on browser

**Solution 2**

try with Firefox, do this before:

1) open this URL in Firefox

about:config

2) Set this: network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris

Set for any cluster DNS domain requiring negotiated authentication (like the kerberos enabled cluster HTTP authentication).

Example:

network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris=.lily.cloudera.com,.solr.cloudera.com

2) Set this: network.auth.use-sspi=false
3) Restart Firefox
4) You have to download the Windows isntaller from here:

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/#kfw-4.0

5) Copy the Kerberos client configuration to here

C:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5\krb5.ini

6) Create a ticket with the MIT kerberos GUI client

7) Try again with Firefox

Hope it can help.

Comment: The OP has SPNs which don't match what is being entered in the web browser, so Kerberos will never work until he fixes that first.  Plus at least one other, if not one or two more problems, which I outlined above.  :-)

Comment: `ksetup /addkdc ksetup /addhosttorealmmap ` complains `/AddHostToRealmMap requires 2 options (only 0 supplied).`