# Getting GSSException: Defective token detected error while calling HDFS API on a kerberised cluster

Tags: python-2.7, api, hadoop, kerberos, cloudera-cdh

I have a kerberised CDH v5.14 cluster with 3 nodes.I trying to call the HDFS API using python as below

```
baseurl = "http://<host_name>:50070/webhdfs/v1/prod/?op=LISTSTATUS"

__, krb_context = kerberos.authGSSClientInit("HTTP/<host_name>")
#kerberos.authGSSClientStep(krb_context, "")
negotiate_details = kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(krb_context)
headers = {"Authorization": "Negotiate " + str(negotiate_details)}
r = requests.get(baseurl, headers=headers)
print r.status_code
```

The below error is returned

```
GSSException: Defective
token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)

HTTP ERROR 403
```

But the same works fine when I run it using **curl**

```
curl -i --negotiate -u: http://<host_name>:50070/webhdfs/v1/prod/?op=LISTSTATUS
```

> HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required Cache-Control:
>   must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store Date: Wed, 30 May 2018 02:50:04 GMT
>   Pragma: no-cache Date: Wed, 30 May 2018 02:50:04 GMT Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 X-FRAME-OPTIONS:
>   SAMEORIGIN WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=;
>   Path=/; HttpOnly Content-Length: 1409
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Expires: Wed, 30 May 2018
>   02:50:04 GMT Date: Wed, 30 May 2018 02:50:04 GMT Pragma: no-cache
>   Expires: Wed, 30 May 2018 02:50:04 GMT Date: Wed, 30 May 2018 02:50:04
>   GMT Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json X-FRAME-OPTIONS:
>   SAMEORIGIN WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
>   YGYGCSqGSIb3EgECAgIAb1cwVaADAgEFoQMCAQ+iSTBHoAMCAReiQAQ+6Seu0SSYGmoqN4hdykSQ55ZcP+juBO/jk8/BGjoK5NCmdlBRFPMSbCZXvVjNHLg9iPACGvM8V0jqXTM5UfQ=
>   Set-Cookie:
>   hadoop.auth="u=XXXX&p=XXXX@HOSTNAME&t=kerberos&e=1527684604664&s=tVsrEsDMBGV0To8hOPp8mLxyiSo=";
>   Path=/; HttpOnly Transfer-Encoding: chunked

and it gives the correct response, what am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227276/gssexception-defective-token-detected-when-trying-to-authenticate-to-tomcat

Comment: @Tagar - It's not related to browser, `curl --negotiate` works however when trying to Authenticate using SPNEGO in Python 2.7 and my question is related to the kerberised Hadoop cluster. Do you have any possible answers to this, that would be appreciated.